# $(f_n)$ a decreasing sequence of integrable function, prove $\int lim f_n \ d\mu = lim \int f \ d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f_n: X\to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable for all natural $n$ such that $f_1\geq f_2 \geq \cdots$ and $\lim f_n = f$. Prove that if $f_1$ is integrable than $$\int f \ d\mu = \lim \int f_n \ d\mu$$

I know that $f_1$ integrable $\implies f_n$ integrable $\forall n$

Then I tried to use LDCT but I couldn't find a integrable function wich dominates $\vert f_n \vert$... I tried $\max\{\vert f_1\vert,\vert f \vert \}$ but I don't know if $f$ is integrable ($\max$ of integrable $f,g$ is integrable because $\max\{f,g\}\leq\vert f \vert + \vert g \vert$, right?)...

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$-f_n + f_1$ is increasing and non-negative. You can apply monotone convergence to that sequence then work backwards using the linearity of the integral and integrability of $f_1$. BTW I don't think your assertion about all $f_n$ being integral is accurate.

Comment: $f_1 \in L \iff \int f_1 \ d\mu < \infty $... but $\int f_n \ d\mu \leq \int f_1 \ d\mu <\infty$.. whats wrong?

Comment: e.g. $f_n=-\infty$

Comment: they are real functions

Comment: @Robson Then $f_n=-1/n$ on the unit interval. My point is you can only get that the positive part has finite integral from these assumptions, not the negative part. You need both to conclude integrability.